# (representation theoretic) meaning of sum over even rows of a Young tableau

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions, young-tableaux

Think of a Young tableau $R$ as composed by
$d$ rows with number of elements $\mu_i:=\mu_i^R$
$\mu_1 \geq \mu_2 \geq \cdots \geq \mu_d > \mu_{d+1}=0$
(and $\mu_i =0\, \forall i >d$)
and define
$\ell(R):=\sum_{i=1}^d \mu_i$.
I'd like to know whether there's any representation theoretic meaning, or anything along the lines of the book *Symmertic Functions and Hall Polynomials* by Macdonald, for the quantities $p$ and $c$, as defined by
$$ p(R) = \sum_i \mu_{2i} = (\ell -c)/2$$

Comment: as the question stands, the sum of even-indexed parts of a partition seems not to have properties of the kind you ask for. But the sum of even parts of a partition does.

Answer (score 1):

For any partition $\lambda $ $\vdash $ n, the RSK (self-) correspondence of any of its tableaux T($\lambda $)*T($\lambda $) produces an involution with cycle structure  $\mu $ $\vdash $ n, with transpose $\mu $' = $\{$a,b$\}$, a+b=n

and a=$\sum$ $\lambda _{2 k-1}$ and b= $\sum $$\lambda _{2 k}$

So, the sum over even-indexed parts equals the number of 2-cycles in $\mu$.